# Why I can't launch VS Code? I get launch-failed error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a issue.
If I try to launch Visual Studio Code i get error: "The window has crashed.(reason: 'launch-failed' code '0')"
and if I try to launch it by cmd i get this error: "spawn EPERM"

No matter if I reinstall, I get always the same error.

Comment: Please provide the version of Visual Studio code you are using.

Comment: It might also help to provide the OS you are using